# c# nested for loops checking comparing each element in list returning odd results

Tags: c#, list, loops, nested, compare

So I have this code... and it is driving me crazy. Results are not consistent and it depends on the order of objects in the list.

Basically duplicates a list of objects, checks each object in the list against each other using compareMembers() (100% no problems with it) then if they have more in common than allowed (num) they are then "similar" and we decide which one to remove. Next whichever has the lower score is removed from the temp list and after all iterations temp list is returned.

Example, if I sort the list prior to removing similar using:

```
group.Sort((a, b) => -1 * a.GroupScore().CompareTo(b.GroupScore()));
```

the returned list always has fewer elements in it, than when I compare similar and the list is completely random. I know the issue lies in this section... hopefully its something simple and I have just been staring at it too long.

Here is the code that is giving conflicting results.

```
    public List<MyGroup> RemoveSimilar(List<MyGroup> group, int num)
    {
        List<MyGroup> temp = group.ToList();

        for(int i = 0; i < group.Count - 1;i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < group.Count;j++)
            {
                   if (group[i].compareMembers(group[j]) > num)
                    {
                        if (group[i].score < group[j].score)
                        {
                            temp.Remove(group[i]);
                            break;//removed this one might as well stop checking it
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            temp.Remove(group[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return temp;
    }
```

Here is the MyGroup class:

```
    public class MyGroup
{
    public Member firstMember;
    public Member secondMember;
    public Member thirdMember;
    public double score;

    public MyGroup()
    {
    }

    public int compareMembers(MyGroup x)
    {

        int i = 0;

        if (this.firstMember == x.firstMember)
        { i++; }
        if (this.secondMember == x.secondMember)
        { i++; }
        if (this.thirdMember == x.thirdMember)
        { i++; }
        if (this.firstMember == x.secondMember)
        { i++; }
        if (this.firstMember == x.thirdMember)
        { i++; }
        if (this.secondMember == x.thirdMember)
        { i++; }

        return i;
    }


    public MyGroup(Member one, Member two, Member three)
    {
        firstMember = one;
        secondMember = two;
        thirdMember = three;


        groupScore = firstMember.mScore + secondMember.mScore + thirdMember.mScore;
    }

    public double GroupScore()
    {

        return score;
    }
}
```

Here is a quick class for the Members that are used to make up the Group:

```
    public class Member
{
    public string idNum;
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public double mScore;


    public Member()
    {
    }

    public Member(string id, string fnm, string lnm, double pt)
    {
        idNum = id;
        firstName = fnm;
        lastName = lnm;
        mScore = pt;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    { return firstName + " " + lastName; }


    public string Desc()
    {
        return idNum + " " + firstName + " " + mScore.ToString();
    }
 }
```

Ok so I reworked it a bit and seem to be getting consistent results regardless of the order of the list.... Would still love to know why the first attempt kept screwing up. Here is the reworked version:

```
        public List<MyGroup> RemoveSimilar(List<MyGroup> group, int num)
    {
        List<MyGroup> temp = group.ToList();//take group argument and copy it into a new list

        for (int i = 0; i < group.Count - 1; i++)//first loop through each element of group list
        {
            if (temp.Contains(group[i])) //checks to make sure group[i] hasn't already been removed from temp list
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < group.Count; j++)//second loop through each element to compare to first
                {
                    if(group[i] != group[j]) //make sure we aren't comparing the same two objects
                    {
                        if (group[i].compareMembers(group[j]) > num)//check to see how "similar" groups are
                        {
                            if (group[i].score < group[j].score)//if the groups are similar, see which has a higher score
                            {
                                temp.Remove(group[i]);//outer element is not the best "unique group" so we remove it
                                break; //removed this one might as well stop checking it
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                temp.Remove(group[j]);//inner element was similar to outter, but not the best so we remove it
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return temp; //return the list after all similar elements have been removed
    }
```

Comment: What is the logic behind group[i].compareMembers(group[j]). I think this should return 0 for equal -1 for what is bigger than other and 1 for other way around. Why you comparing it to random number ?

Comment: Can you please also include the definition of `MyGroup` which implements `compareMembers` and `score`? That is - a snippet of code that we can simply copy + paste and immediately replicate the issue? At a quick glance, `compareMembers` may pass for `A:B`, and `B:C`, but not for `A:C`. Which means the order of execution *matters*.

Comment: logic behind comparemembers is that it looks at the two MyGroup objects and finds out how many "members" they have in common. That is compared with how many are allowed (num).. could be one, or two, etc. Then if they have more than I want, they should be removed. Basically this is supposed to find unique combinations within a large list.

Comment: I think you want your comparMembers to return the same results if its called using x.compareMembers(y) or y.compareMembers(x). Now it seem to not check all members against eachother equally.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. @FredrikLundvall im not too sure I follow. If you were to execute code x.compareMembers(y) == y.compareMembers(x) it would return true.

Comment: Added some more code at the bottom... I believe this is a good solution. Would love somebody to verify my logic though... also if somebody can tell me why the first version didn't work I would appreciate it. Worked through it so many times and still can't figure out why it was failing.

The 2nd version should be faster anyways because it will not go through the inner loop if that object was already removed from the temp list.

Comment: @marateon If you want to see it try {A,B,C}.compareTo({C,D,E}). It will return 0 because this.thirdMember is never checked. But when calling {C,D,E}.compareTo({A,B,C}) it returns 1. Because this.firstMember == x.thirdMember. It's a perfect place for unittesting.

Comment: @FredrikLundvall I think I see what you are saying. Except in my case the compareMembers method in the group class handles all combinations, increments my var and returns it.

if you look it compares:
1->1,2->2,3->3,1->2,1->3,2->3

which works for my needs. it shows me how many members within each group are duplicate and returns that number.

im sure there is a more elegant solution but that popped into my head first

Comment: @marateon The problem is the combinations, if you also cover the cases 2->1, 3->1,3->2 then you will get the same result when calling x.compareMembers(y) and y.compareMembers(x). _Btw I wrote compareTo() but I meant compareMembers()_

Comment: @FredrikLundvall 2->1 is the same as 1->2, 3->1 is 1->3, etc. if i added those remaining three then my int i will increment higher than the number of members in the group because 2->1 will increment as well as 1->2. those three were left out intentionally. Note this does not return a boolean, it returns an int.

Comment: @marateon If you don't want the returned number to exceed the number of members you can add them in the check like this: `if (this.firstMember == x.secondMember || this.secondMember == x.firstMember)`

Answer (score 0):

When you have a function that is defined like this:

```
class MyGroup 
{
   public int compareMembers(MyGroup x);
}
```

It can be important to consider the case when you change the calling object with the parameter. You usally want the same results from the following calls:

```
x.compareMembers(y);
y.compareMembers(x);
```

In your case you need to change the function compareMembers to this:

```
public int compareMembers(MyGroup x)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (this.firstMember == x.firstMember)
    { i++; }
    if (this.secondMember == x.secondMember)
    { i++; }
    if (this.thirdMember == x.thirdMember)
    { i++; }
    if (this.firstMember == x.secondMember || this.secondMember == x.firstMember)
    { i++; }
    if (this.firstMember == x.thirdMember || this.thirdMember == x.firstMember )
    { i++; }
    if (this.secondMember == x.thirdMember || this.thirdMember == x.secondMember )
    { i++; }
    return i;
}
```

As a side note the function name could be countEqualMembers for more clarity in the purpose of the function.